# Map with multiple keys and values

Tags: kotlin

I'm making a quiz app in Kotlin where there is a question with between 2 and 5 answer options together with scores. So there is the question number, question, answers and points for each answer. I have made the app in flutter where I used Map with one key (question number: question) and another key (answer option: score). The answer used a list for the multiple options. What would be the best way to do it in Kotlin?

Flutter code

```
{
      'Question 1': 'Do you ...?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Not at all', 'score': 0},
        {'text': 'Partly', 'score': 50},
        {'text': 'Mostly', 'score': 280},
        {'text': 'Completely', 'score': 500},
      ],
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Lena Bru for the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357102/844313) answer, which unfortunately had a few bugs in it. This should be a working version that addresses your question:

data classes:

```kotlin
data class Answer(
    @SerializedName("text") val text: String = "",
    @SerializedName("score") val score: Int = 0
)

data class Question(
    @SerializedName("Question") val questionText: String = "",
    val answers: List<Answer> = listOf()
)
```

json data:

```kotlin
val json = """
[
    {
        "Question": "Why?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "text": "Because I said so",
                "score": 10
            },
            {
                "text": "Dunno",
                "score": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
"""
```

And finally, parsing the json and displaying it:

```kotlin
val gson = Gson()
val questions: List<Question> = gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<List<Question?>?>() {}.type)


questions.forEach { question ->
    println("The question is: ${question.questionText}")
    println("The answers are:")
    question.answers.forEach {answer ->
        println("    Text: ${answer.text}, score: ${answer.score}")
    }
}
```

The main differences with the previous answer:

- changed json to match data classes
- json is now a string
- Fixed display code

Hope this helps and is still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
data class Answer(@SerializedName("text") val text: String = "", @SerializedName("score") score: Int = 0)

data class Question(@SerializedName("Question") val questionText: String = "", answers: List<Answer> = listOf())
```

In my opinion your json structure is not good, because you have a number inside the question key, i.e "Question 1"

I would structure it the following way:

```
json = [
   { "Question": "why is blabla a blabla?",
     "answers": ["because I said so", "who knows?", "It doesnt matter"]
    },
    { "Question": "Is this a second question because it is an array of questions?",
      "answers": ["Yes", "No", "White", "Black"]
    }
]
```

When you put that json through gson for example (the common google json parser)

```
val questions: List<Question> = gson.fromJson(json,TypeToken<List<Question>(){}.type)


 questions.forEach { question ->
    Log.d("TAG","The question is:${question.questionText}"
    Log.d("TAG","The answers are: ${question.answers.contentToString()}"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a few errors "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)". json = [ { "Question": "why is blabla a blabla?", "answers": ["because I said so", "who knows?", "It doesnt matter"] }, { "Question": "Is this a second question because it is an array of questions?", "answers": ["Yes", "No", "White", "Black"] } ] How would I fix this?